# Altering a native prototype before content load in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a simple Chrome extension which will change the prototype of the `Date` object. I want the flow to be like the following.

- `inject.js` loads
- `inject.js` runs and changes `setHours` on the `Date` prototype
- The rest of the page will use the `setHours` that I have now defined

My `inject.js`:

```
Date.prototype.setHours = function () {
  alert();
};
```

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  // ... 
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*"],
      "js": ["inject.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that I use the `run_at` property to instruct the script to run before any JS is loaded on the page. This seems to work as I invoked `debugger` and the page did not load.

I understand this may be explicitly blocked as it seems like it could maybe be a security issue? Though I have not seen any mention of modifying the prototype chain being disallowed.

I am unfortunately getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')`

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that directly from `inject.js` due to security as you said. `inject.js` would have to write another script into the document e.g.

```
const dateScript = document.createElement('script');
dateScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('date-modifier.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).prepend(dateScript);
```

Comment: I have implemented this but I needed to change my manifest to run at `document_end`. It appends the script successfully, but it is not run before the original JS on the page is run.

Comment: Is there even any way for me to delay the code on the page?

Comment: Use inline code as shown in [Use a content script to access the page context variables and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)